# Else if with foreach is not working

Tags: php, foreach

This scripts reads the text from array I using else if it does not work but if I use if it work I want use else if can anyone suggest a way how to do that

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["maininput"])){
foreach($id as $uni){
    if (preg_match("/" . $uni . "/i", $_POST['maininput'])){
        $founda = $uni;
        $data = $uni . "\n";
        $fname = "accepted.txt";
        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');//creates new file
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        break;
   }

}
}else if{
foreach($coures as $mac){
    if (preg_match("/" . $mac . "/i", $_POST['maininput'])){
        $found = $mac;
        $data = $mac;
        $fname = "accepted.txt";//generates random name
        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');//creates new file
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        break;
    }

}
}else{
foreach($university as $un => $unis){
    if (preg_match("/" . $un . "/i", $_POST['maininput'])){
        $founde = $unis;
        //$data = serialize($unis);
        $fname = "accepted.txt";//generates random name
        file_put_contents($fname, $unis, FILE_APPEND);

        //$file = fopen($fname, 'a');//creates new file
        //fwrite($file, $data);
        //fclose($file);
        break;


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have written the same condition within if and else if statements. Aren't there any specific array keys within $_REQUEST to distinguish between the two?

Comment: When you have multiple if statements, it executes all of them. But for if and else if, when the if condition satisfies, it doesn't execute the else if one.

Comment: yeah there it is form

Comment: i have edit my code bro still not working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Seems to have a syntax error. You need to write something within else if(...). Could you print_r the $_REQUEST array and explain what exactly you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: that `elseif` - `foreach` is failing you. Use `else`. That should have thrown you something about it.

Comment: i doing a collage practical in which i send text  to file  <form id = "fetch">
 ID:<br>
 <span id="courseid"><?php echo $founda; ?></span>
 <br>
 Courses:<br>
 <span id ="courses"><?php echo $found; ?> </span>
 <br>
 University:<br>
 <select multiple>
 
 <?php
 foreach ($founde as $uni) {
  echo "<option>$uni</option>";
 }
 ?>

 
  </select>
    <button type="button" id = "napier" >Sumbit</button>
  </form>

Comment: please don't dump code in comments. Edit your question  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35959599/edit

Comment: i have to  use elseif  because i have two more if condition fred lii

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: i have tried this but still not working

Comment: read carrefully @PerfectM answer.

Comment: no please help mee

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Syntax is wrong

```
if(condition) {
  //magic
}
else if(other_condiotion) {
  //other magic
}
else {
 //no magic
}
```

Or you can use shorten version:

```
$var = (condition) ? true : false;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

EDIT:
It is hard to understand your problem but it seems you want to do that:

```
$found = null;
$founda = null;
if(isset($_REQUEST["maininput"])){
foreach($id as $uni){
    if (preg_match("/" . $uni . "/i", $_POST['maininput'])){
        $founda = $uni;
        $data = $uni . "\n";
        $fname = "accepted.txt";
        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');//creates new file
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        break;
      }

   }
}
else {
    foreach($coures as $mac) {
    if (preg_match("/" . $mac . "/i", $_POST['maininput'])){
        $found = $mac;
        $data = $mac;
        $fname = "accepted.txt";//generates random name
        $file = fopen($fname, 'a');//creates new file
        fwrite($file, $data);
        fclose($file);
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

If you do not provide any extra second condition to check use `if(condition_match) {} else {//conditon doesn't match}`

Use `else if` when you have 2 or more condition to check like:

```
$number = 3
if($number == 1) { //false
 //This is number 1
}
else if($number == 2) { //false
 //This is number 2
}
else { //true
 //This is number 3
}
```

It is clear now?
Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: i have edited the code please have a look

Comment: bro  do you mean i can"t use else if here

Comment: To use `else if` you must pass condition. You do not do that in your code.